# Is there any way to change or append the IDEA's console output with GrepConsole?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, mybatis

Is there any way to change or append the IDEA's console output?

I hava a demand to change or append the console content in IDEA.
for example, when the mybatis framework output the prepare statement sql like below:

```
2016-10-08 11:00:00.009 DEBUG c.o.m.b.e.B.updateByPrimaryKeySelective -  -  - ==>  Preparing: select * from tablename where (id=?)
2016-10-08 11:00:00.010 DEBUG c.o.m.b.e.B.updateByPrimaryKeySelective -  -  - ==> Parameters: 123456789(String)
```

I want to replace the ? to really value like this:

```
select * from tablename where (id='123456789')
```

and append behind the next line.

I hava an idea to achieve it through the GrepConsole plugin.
But when i read the source code and try to change the filter class code many way, and redeploy the plugin.
And the plugin has not been effective.

The GrepConsole plugin can change the console content's color and font style, can it change console content isself?

Or there are other ways to achieve the above needs?

Anyone know this any help me please?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As an author of GrepConsole plugin, the easiest would be to just debug the plugin, and do small changes which the hotswap can handle. Changing the InputFilter would be the right way.

Or you could probably make some filter in your logback/log4j...

It would be nice to add some dynamic scriptable transformation filter for such things, pull request welcome.

> Edit: [GrepConsole](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin now supports changing of output by scripting.

Comment: I tried it with GrepInputFilterTest.java, and append the output str, In Junit test is display ok, but when deploy in plugin, the append content can't show out.

Comment: How do you deploy it?

Comment: Right click the project and select "Prepare Plugin Module 'GrepConsole' For Deployment", and install it again in Plugins interface. select "Install plugin from disk...", and restart the idea.

Comment: Sounds good, and did you try debugging the plugin in Idea instance? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-and-debugging-plugins.html

Comment: below is my try result: